# Web App's Receive Data Slower

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make web apps of Point of Sales.
i have try to use J-Query, Ajax for receive data from database MySQL.
But, why it's so slow..
http://250109.hol.es/Coba/examples/coba.php

I Want to make Fast web apps like this example
http://250109.hol.es/Coba/examples/new.php (Receive data from JavaScript array)

Here's my code:(in Ajax)

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            url: "weq.php",
            data: "id_barang="+id_barang,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                id_barang = data[0];
                nama_barang = data[1];
                satuan = data[3];
                harga_beli = data[4];
                harga_jual = data[5];
            }
        });
```

My PHP

```
<?php
include ("../tes.php");
$id_barang = $_POST["id_barang"];
$hasil = mysql_query("select * from tb_barang where id_barang = $id_barang");
$array = mysql_fetch_row($hasil);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

echo json_encode($array);

Comment: There will always be a time lag when retrieving data from a database. This is due to the fact that javascript needs to make the XHR request, load the server-side script, process the instruction, connect to the database, the database to retrieve the data and send it back to the calling app. The app needs to format and send this data to the xhr caller. Admittedly this should only take a addition second or two

Comment: is `id_barang` indexed? do you need every row(*) if not list only the ones you need

Comment: " will always be a time lag when retrieving data from a database"
so i can't get the data more faster? 

yes, id_barang is indexed..